# is it true that $a^{n-4}b^4 = a^{n}b^{4n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am reading "Precalculus mathematics in a nutshell" and on page 40 there is an exercice with the answer at the end. they ask to simplify:
$a^{n-4}b^4$

The answer key shows:
$a^{n}b^{4n}$
But I personally get $\frac{(a^nb^4)}{a^4}$ when I do it. I dont seem to find a way to get the same answer than in the book. What am I missing?

Comment: The answer key is wrong.

Comment: I think $a^{n-4}b^4$ is simple enough as it is. But beware "the answers at the back of the book"; these are not always thoroughly checked and are frequently erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct and the answer key is incorrect.

The $a^{n-4}$ term can be split into $a^na^{-4}=\frac{a^n}{a^4}$, giving your answer.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is what i thought